# What is the "watch" feature actually doing with SASS?

Tags: sass

when using sass i'm a little confused on the purpose of the watch feature. Is it primarily used for terminal to literally see the changes being updated from scss to css.

OR if i just use  `sass --watch scss:css` it will "watch" all my files in those folders (named `scss` and `css`).

I see Atom making these changes in real time also. I know the watch feature connects the 2 files, but every time I see someone use sass they have a  terminal bash open with a css and scss window.

Does atom also do the same thing as terminal here and the only set up needed would then be?

```
sass --watch scss:css
```

Comment: The problem here is what, exactly?

Comment: Long story short, read the **[Using Sass](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html)** section

Comment: Short answer: **YES**.

Comment: @cimmanon its comments like yours, that make many noob's like myself never want to ask for help... : /

Comment: You've obviously seen what the watch argument does for yourself, so it is unclear why you are even asking this question.  Did you bother doing any research at all before asking this question (either via the Sass documentation, which is a single page long, or via `sass --help`)?  Please, by all means, avoid asking questions before you've done any research for yourself.

Comment: @cinammon yes thank you next time I will include my entire life story in each stack post for you haha... seems like everyone else who responded actually understood what i was asking, your contribution was nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It watches the file for changes. Once it sees changes after a save it processes the scss file into a css file.